# Enviar Correo con HTML y archivos adjuntos

Tags: django

deseo enviar un email con código **HTML** tipo los de publicidad y archivos adjuntos adicionales(xml, pdf), actualmente solo envia texto plano:

```
def EnviarEmailAdjuntos(asunto, mensaje, destinatario_list, adjuntos):

    #importamos configuraciones
    from django.conf import settings
    Envia = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
    import json
    from smtplib import SMTPException

    try:
        email = EmailMessage(asunto, mensaje,Envia,destinatario_list)
        if adjuntos:
            for file in adjuntos:
                email.attach_file(file)
        email.send()

        json_destinatarios = json.dumps(destinatario_list)
        correo = Correo(
            destinatario = json_destinatarios,
            asunto = asunto,
            mensaje = mensaje,
            estado = 1,
            adjunto = None,
        )
        correo.save()

        print "ok_email"

    except SMTPException as e:
        print('There was an error sending an email: ', e)
        correo = Correo(
            destinatario = json_destinatarios,
            asunto = asunto,
            mensaje = mensaje,
            estado = 0,
             adjunto = None
        )
        correo.save()
```

La idea es enviar un correo con el siguiente HTML:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td colspan=2>
      <img src="http://pruebarg.rgmanagementcorp.com/logo.png" alt="RGmanagementcorp" >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Saludos Cordiales mediante la presente adjuntamos su Factura Electronica con los siguientes datos:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Autorizacion</b></td>
    <td>{{num_autorizacion}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Clave</b></td>
    <td>{{ clave }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Fec. Autorizacion</b></td>
    <td>{{ fec_autorizacion }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center;">
    <td colspan="2">
    <div style="float: rigth;">
    RGmanagementcorp agradece su confianza.
    </div>
    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alguna sugerencia, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar el `attach_file` pasándole la ruta de tu archivo en el servidor:

```
message.attach_file('/images/logo.png')
```

Probablemente tu variable `adjuntos` no contenga la ruta. Asegúrate de que la ruta es correcta y encuentra el fichero, en caso contrario no lo adjuntará al email.